# Tools for comparing dependencies in a Java project

Tags: linux, java

I have two Java projects managed with different dependency/delivery tools and want to know the differences of the required dependencies.

I am using Linux (CentOS) in a VM but a Windows solution can be acceptable.

The first project which is the original is based on Ant scripting and the dependencies are hardcoded somewhere there, all the needed libraries in a `lib` folder, and then a `build.properties` have a mapping `alias=name-version.jar`

The second project is a maven project based on the first one but we added and updated some dependencies.

My goal is to find a tool (if it exists) to make a report thats say something similar to this:

Project 2 - new dependencies:

- Joda Time version 2.1
- Google GSON version 3.2
- Apache CXF 2.5
- DWR version 3.2-beta

Project 2 - updated dependencies:

- Apache commons lang from 1.2 to 1.6
- Apache Commons IO from 2.1 to 2.4
- slf4j From 2.4 to 2.6

Project 2 - removed dependencies

- Log4j version 1.2
- Castor version 2.1

Note: the version are not reflecting the reality, it is just to show an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody has recommended such a tool (in 3 months), I'm going to suggest an alternative approach using existing tools.

Step 1: extract the dependencies.

- for the Any project, either `ls` the `lib` directory, or write a simple script to extract the list from the `build.properties` file.
- for the Maven project, you can extract the list from the output of `mvn dependency:list`.  (See [this blog posting](http://grep.codeconsult.ch/2010/07/08/list-all-your-maven-dependencies/) for an example.)

Step 2: sort the lists

Step 3: use the `diff` command to see the differences.

Comment: Let me add this package: http://tattletale.jboss.org/ -- it will look into every jar in your `lib` directory for detailed information.

Comment: Thanks, finally it was the 'manual' solution I applied. Thanks also to Linux bash utils which are quite more useful than the ones under Windows. (Sed and Awk are so powerful)